# Specify Windows User when using nuget on a shared folder

Tags: msbuild, nuget, nuget-package, .net-standard, msbuild-15

I'm scripting the update of some nuget packages to my shared folder (MSBuild 15):

```
\\myserver\packages
```

I changed the Windows User that have access to this shared folder to be: NugetUser.

I can access the share from Explorer, using the NugetUser credentials.

But when I use:

```
nuget add new_package.1.0.0.nupkg -source \\myserver\packages
```

or:

```
nuget init c:\packages \\myserver\packages
```

I cannot drop the packages on the share because I have no permission. How can I specify the user from the script?

My script is a simple batch file:

```
@echo off

nuget init .\packages \\myserver\packages

:END
echo "End"
pause
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found following solution:

```
@echo off

net use \\myserver\packages /user:myserver\User password
nuget init .\packages \\myserver\packages

:END
echo "End"
pause
```